# Hide DIV element in iframe

Tags: javascript, html

I have a iframe, where I try hide one div element (frame with facebook).

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeCSS(){
 frame = document.getElementById("radar");
 frame.contentWindow.document.getElementById("div_facebook").style.display='none';
}
</script>
```

```html
<iframe name="radar" 
onload="javascript:changeCSS()" 
id="radar" 
width="650" 
height="450" 
frameborder="0" 
scrolling="no" 
src="http://radar.bourky.cz/index.php?lat=49.9847&lon=16.6241&zoom=8&map=0&repeat=3&last=4&r_opa=30&l_opa=10&l_type=0&cell=0&anim=1&c1=0&c2=0&c3=0&c4=0&c5=0">
</iframe>
```

And here is problem from console in chrome:

*index.html:85 Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
    at changeCSS (file:///D:/jirka/Desktop/kalend%C3%A1%C5%99/index.html:85:21)
    at HTMLIFrameElement.onload (file:///D:/jirka/Desktop/kalend%C3%A1%C5%99/index.html:96:170)*

I have read many instructions, but problem weren't solved.
If anyone could help I'd be very much appreciated.

Comment: You can't access cross-domain pages via JS. [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: In order to get something done accross domains, refer window postmessage.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you can't modify the contents of an iframe unless the domain of both the main page and the iframe are the same.

I'm guessing from what you pasted that they aren't the same, since it looks like the outer is being run locally and the iframe is from a domain (`radar.bourky.cz`).

You won't be able to manipulate it with JavaScript from the outside. That's a security precaution to prevent malevolent actors from doing bad things with websites. You won't be able to get around it unless you control the code both inside and outside.

Comment: _I'm guessing from what you pasted that they aren't the same, since it looks like the outer is being run locally and the iframe is from a domain [link](radar.bourky.cz) _ This is true
If I understand correctly, so I must use other way.

For Example: [link](embed.windy.com)